# Is reflection is for classloader?

Tags: java, reflection, jvm

I know that reflection is a technique for calling methods or manipulating bytecode without knowing the concrete type.

Recently, while studying classloaders, I came across an article that reflection is for classloaders to dynamically load classes and do type checking. Is this true?

#### The article

The original text is not in English, so the translation may be a bit strange.

> Java dynamically loads classes. That is, all code is linked to the JVM at runtime. Every class is dynamically linked to the JVM and loaded into memory at the moment that class is referenced. Java's runtime library ([JDK installation directory]/jre/lib/rt.jar) is no exception. This dynamic class loading is done through the class loader system of Java, and the class loader provided by Java is expressed through java.lang.ClassLoader. When the JVM starts, it creates a bootstrap class loader and then reads the first class, Object, into the system.
>
> Loading a class dynamically at runtime means that the JVM has no information about the class. In other words, the JVM does not know information about methods, fields, and inheritance relationships of classes. Therefore, the classloader should be able to obtain the necessary information when loading a class and check whether the class is correct. If you can't do this, the JVM may have mismatched versions of the .class files, and it will be impossible to type-check. The JVM has the ability to analyze classes internally, and from JDK 1.1, developers can analyze these classes through reflection.

Comment: Add the quote from the article that you’re referring to

Comment: First of all, please take into account that the translation may be awkward because the article is not in English.

Comment: Loading a class dynamically at runtime means that the JVM has no information about the class. In other words, the JVM does not know information about methods, fields, and inheritance relationships of classes. Therefore, the classloader should be able to obtain the necessary information when loading a class and check whether the class is correct. If you can't do this, the JVM may have mismatched versions of the .class files, and it will be impossible to type-check. The JVM has the ability to analyze classes internally, and from JDK 1.1, developers can analyze these classes through reflection.

Comment: "please take into account that the translation may be awkward" nonetheless, we can't explain or opine on an article without seeing it. If the quote in the previous comment is an excerpt from the article, please [edit] your question to add it; and also include a link to the original article.

Comment: sorry. I eddited

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nothing in this cited text allows the conclusion that Reflection is “for classloaders”.

The text ends with “… and from JDK 1.1, developers can analyze these classes through reflection” which is an additional information that stands for itself. The fact that the text talked about class loaders before, has no relevance here.

Mentioning the version number when it boils down to “practically since the beginning”, suggests that this is a rather old text. This explains the part

> Therefore, the classloader should be able to obtain the necessary information when loading a class and check whether the class is correct.

Class loaders don’t do this at all. But in Java 1.0 and partly in Java 1.1, class loaders were indeed deemed responsible for linking and verification tasks. This has been cleaned up with JDK 1.2, also known as Java 2. Since then, the class loader’s responsibility is restricted to locating the necessary resource and loading it into a byte array, to be passed to the JVM. Linking and Verification is the JVM’s job, which implies that it will also protect itself against potentially broken class loaders.

Since the class loader’s job is just reading files, sockets, or other resources into byte arrays and passing them to the JVM, they don’t have any need for Reflection APIs on their own.

Answer (score 5):

Reflection is specifically the ability of *Java code* to inspect already loaded Java classes and interact with them dynamically (i.e. not just call methods or access fields that were already known at compile time).

What the JVM does when loading a class is similar, in that it inspects the bytecode to get an understanding what parts make up a class and to check for correctness, but it's not reflection in the sense written above: it does *not* use the same APIs, as they are limited to a higher-level view. In effect the reflection APIs in Java only come into play once the JVM has already fully analyzed and "understood" a class.

Note that the classloader itself doesn't actually need to understand classes: it only provides their raw bytecode to the JVM to load them. All it must do is *locate that bytecode and load it into memory*.

Answer (score 3):

> Is reflection is for classloader?

Basically ... no.

Most of the classloader Java code is about finding classes and resources on the classpath.  When it decides it needs to load a class, it calls a internal native method to convert (typically) a `byte[]` or `ByteBuffer` containing the classfile representation into a loaded class.  That native method uses infrastructure that is beneath the reflection APIs that regular Java code uses.

On the other hand, applications use reflection for many things, so even if a classloader did use reflection, you cannot say that reflection is *for* the classloader.  It is *for* ... lots of things.

Reflection is a bit of a rubbery term ... but the general idea is that it is about a program *looking at* or *thinking about* itself.  In this context, the JVM is not the program.  It is the machine that runs the program.  Class loading and maintaining runtime type safety are fundamental functions of the JVM ... whereas the reflection APIs are a *service* that the JVM provides to (Java, etc) applications running on / in the JVM.

---

Also ...

> I know that reflection is a technique for ... manipulating bytecode ...

Actually, reflection doesn't allow you to "manipulate" bytecode in the conventional sense.  That kind of thing (so-called "bytecode engineering") is done by a different kind of library.  It happens before the bytecodes are loaded.

---

It is a bit difficult to understand what the quoted text is actually say, not least because of the translation.  But I don't think it is saying that the classloader *needs* to use reflection.

> Therefore, the classloader should be able to obtain the necessary information when loading a class and check whether the class is correct.

Correct.

> If you can't do this, the JVM may have mismatched versions of the .class files, and it will be impossible to type-check.

Correct.

> The JVM has the ability to analyze classes internally,

Correct.  But it doesn't say that the JVM is using reflection to do this.  It is using (unspecified) internal mechanisms.  They do not involve making calls to the reflection APIs.  Even in the Java 1.0 / 1.1 days when the `ClassLoader` class was responsible for linking and verify (according to @Holger's answer) they would have parsed the classfile directly rather than using reflection APIs.

> and from JDK 1.1, developers can analyze these classes through reflection.

This is a bit of a non-sequitur ... but I think that the correct way to read this is that developers can **also** access the type information.  It is not saying that classloaders and Java programs use the same (reflection) APIs to access the type information.

In summary, I think you are misreading what the article is saying.

Comment: There is some weirdness in these statements, as a JVM that is expected to parse a class and interpret its bytecode, should also be expected to be able to check the class or in other words, understand it. I think, the reason is that this is an ancient text or based on outdated information, from a time when this job was truly intended to be done by the class loader.

Comment: Agreed.  If only we had a link to the article ...